# Htaccess rewrite rules to redirect multiple domains

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect some domains correctly using the htaccess file. Here is what I got:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^special.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://website.com/some-special-page [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^website.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://website.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**Why is *special.com* also redirecting to *website.com* and not to *website.com/some-special-page* ?**

The overall redirect for all the other domains is working fine, however I can't figure out how to have this special case work (and not be overwritten by the second rule. Thanks in advance!

Comment: does special.com with www ? like www.special.com

Comment: special.com and www.special.com both are redirecting directly to website.com

Comment: from your code you match only special.com  and if it comes with www it will not match, paste your htaccess file

Comment: Oh just emptied my browser cache and it worked... Drove me nuts for an hour, didn't think of this.. Thanks for pointing out that www will not work, I will fix this now!

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?special.com$ put this to match both

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Glad to help , Thanks